# Check if a line in a bash_profile

Tags: bash, shell

What would be the correct way to check if a string is in my bash_profile. For example:

```
if [ grep 'VIM' ~/.bash_profile ] then
    echo 'yes!'
else
    echo 'no!'
fi
```

In other words, I want to check to see if the literal string `*VIM` is contained in my `bash_profile`.

I tried doing the following:

```
MATCHED_LINE=$(grep 'VIM,TMUX' ~/.bash_profile)
echo $MATCHED_LINE
if [ -z $MATCHED_LINE ]
```

But get the error:

> ./test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments

Comment: `grep -q '\*VIM' ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Force the variable `$MATCHED_LINE` to stay as one string by wrapping it with double quotes, like this:  `if [ -z "$MATCHED_LINE" ]`